# Yii2 - Union query with Pagination into ActiveRecord

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a case where I need to have a **union query**, and at the same time have the end result as **ActiveRecord**. To illustrate, I have two tables **Products** and **Categories**. Each has a model that extends from ActiveRecord. I'm trying to have a query as follows

```
$deletedProducts = Products::find()->select([$productsTable . '.id', $productsTable . '.selling_price'])
                ->where(['client' => $clientId])
                ->andWhere(['<>', 'hidden', 0]);
```

and

```
$deletedCats = Category::find()->select([$catTable . '.id', $catTable . '.selling_price'])
                ->where(['client' => $clientId])
                ->andWhere(['<>', 'hidden', 0]);
```

and

```
$archivedItemsQuery = $deletedProducts->union($deletedCats);
```

I then return the results through **ActiveDataProvider**

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(
            [
                'query' => $archivedItemsQuery,
        ]
    ]);
return $dataProvider->getModels();
```

The problem is that when I try to send pagination data in the request, or set it through the ActiveDataProvider, no pagination happens. I can change this query of course to

```
$unionQuery = (new \yii\db\Query())
                ->from(['counter_items' => $archivedItemsQuery]);
```

This results in correct pagination, but I dont get the result as **ActiveRecords**.

Any ideas on how to create a union query with **1. Pagination working and 2. The result is ActiveRecord.**

Comment: what if you write it `$dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' =>Products::find()->from(['products' => $archivedItemsQuery]),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 8,
            ],
        ]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi can you try the following, not very neatest of the ways but I hope it works for you I tested it on my end and if I understand correctly you want the result of `$dataProvider->getModels()` to return an `ActiveRecord` Models Object i.e `Products` model and want the `GridView` pagination to work correctly at the same time.

You need to change the `ActiveDataProvider` to use the union `$archivedItemsQuery` in the following way.

```
$dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Products::find()->from(['products' => $archivedItemsQuery]),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
]);
```

Comment: I think there is a neater way, but this works perfectly. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I a not sure but can you try once to use `Products::findBySql($archivedItems-Query->createCommand()->rawSql)` for the `query` parameter I think it should work in a neat way too, I will update my answer in case it works, not on my seat so cant check at the moment. @mrateb